# Google OpenID & OAuth - How to get access tokens

Tags: python, oauth, access-token, google-openid

I have a website from where I want users to link their GMail account, I later want access to the users GMail account through OAuth. I use [**Google's OpenID+OAuth**](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) (Hybrid Protocol) for this.

When I follow the above mentioned documentation, I get the following -

```
openid.assoc_handle AOQobUfg8E9PvTYX1huZPleVGoSvky57TxLHMzI-Lxd87cDNwLyrutSm
openid.claimed_id   https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlus8fqLMQGgfCCM6pDZGpuNjwQqqYMs4o
openid.ext1.mode    fetch_response
openid.ext1.type.email  http://axschema.org/contact/email
openid.ext1.value.email forward@gmail.com
**openid.ext2.request_token   4/C-VqYG9lRtJBKM9G15I-tFk58rOS**
openid.ext2.scope   https://mail.google.com/
openid.identity https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlus8fqLMQGgfCCM6pDZGpuNjwQqqYMs4o
openid.mode id_res
openid.ns   http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
openid.ns.ext1  http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
openid.ns.ext2  http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
openid.op_endpoint  https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
openid.response_nonce   2011-05-07T18:38:37ZOEVDbKdW6d2g9A
openid.return_to    https://mysite.com/gmail_redir/
openid.sig  niD5l9V7cG+LOE2zYjJ6rS0Cdwc=
openid.signed   op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,ns.ext1,ns.ext2,ext1.mode,ext1.type.email,ext1.value.email,ext2.scope,ext2.request_token
```

I get the **openid.ext2.request_token** which is supposed to allow me to crawl the users GMail acc. through OAuth. How does that work? Don't I need access tokens (i.e. oauth_access_secret and oauth_access_token)??

Do I need to make any more requests? Anyone know how to proceed after this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a token, you must

1. authorize it, and then
2. exchange it for an access token

Take a look at http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html#WorkingOauth

or https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 (for OAuth v2)